# Enter some inputs in terminal after executing a tool

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

Need to write a code to execute a tool in linux terminal and fill its questions out.

For example there is a tool called xyztool which has two flags "-H" for the remote IP address and "-U" for getting the username.
When this tool executes, it asks for the **old password**, **new password** and **retype new password**.

I want to write a code to execute the tool, then enter the inputs automatically one after the other.

```
$ xyztool -U admin
Old password: ****
New password: *****
Retype New password: *****
```

This is what I wrote already, but I really don't know how to use IO module, so I just tried it!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys
import io

def main_cmds():
    '''execute xyztool and fill its prompts out'''
    cmds = subprocess.call(["xyztool", "-H", "172.16.10.10", "-U", "admin"])

print(main_cmds())


def go_run():
    f1 = sys.stdin
    f = io.StringIO('oldP@ssw0rd')
    sys.stdin = f
    main_cmds()
    f.close()
    sys.stdin = f1

print(go_run())
```

Comment: @High-Octane No, infact the tool asks as I wrote above. And I want to write a code to automate this process every some seconds, because the password resets to the old one every some seconds... It's for security testing of a server.

Comment: @High-Octane the tool is smbpasswd